# Redirect to a file output of remote python app started through ssh

Tags: python, bash, ssh, stdout, pid

[EDITED]

I have a python app in a remote server that i need to debug, when I run the app locally it prints some debug information (including python tracebacks) that i need to monitor.

Thanks to [jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356721/jeremy) i got to monitor the output file using *tail -F* and studying his code I got [here](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/working-with-python-subprocess.html) where i found the following variation of his command:

```
ssh root@$IP 'nohup python /root/python/run_dev_server.py &>> /var/log/myapp.log &'
```

This gets me almost exactly what i want, loggin information and python tracebacks, but i do not get any of the information displayed using *print* from python which i need.

so I also tried his command:

```
ssh root@$IP 'nohup python /root/python/run_dev_server.py 2>&1 >> /var/log/myapp.log &'
```

it logs in the file the output of the program from *print* and also the logging information, but all the tracebacks are lost so i cannot debug the python exceptions.

Is there a way I can capture all the information produced by the app?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
/usr/bin/nohup COMMAND  ARGS 2>&1 >> /var/log/COMMAND.log &
/bin/echo $! > /var/run/COMMAND.pid
```

nohup keeps the process alive after your terminal/ssh session is closed, >> will save all stdout and stderr to /var/log/COMMAND.log for you to "tail -f" later on.

To get the stacktrace output (which you could print to stdout, or do something fancy like email it)  add the following lines to your python code.

```
    import sys
    import traceback
    _old_excepthook = sys.excepthook
    def myexcepthook(exctype, value, tb):
            # if exctype == KeyboardInterrupt:  # handle keyboard events
            # Print to stdout for now, but could email or anything here.
            print traceback.print_tb(tb);
            _old_excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys.excepthook = myexcepthook
```

This will catch all exceptions (Including keyboard interrupts, so be careful)

Comment: Sounds good, do you know if nohup is going to add the output of the program to the log until it finishes? or does it do it as the program prints?

Comment: nohup, by default, puts standard out in a file called nohup.out if it has not already been redirected.  (the command above appends all stdout and stderr to /var/log/command.log).  I would also suggest looking into the command 'screen' (http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) which may solve your problem as well.

Comment: hey jeremy i tried the command and it worked fine except for one thing, not all output from the program is redirected to the file, any traceback from python still appears in my local console and does not let me use it, is it supposed to be like that or there is something else i have to add to the command?